# Жаргон и сленг: одно и то же или нет?

Tags: жаргон, значение-слов

Как мы знаем, жаргон - это "язык" некой группы людей, объединенных общим делом. Например, на торговом жаргоне будет не "разлив", а "рОзлив", не "яйца", а "яйцо" (во мн. числе). Сленг - это как бы тоже набор слов определенно группы людей, например, молодежи.
Так что ж, выходит, что жаргон и сленг отличаются только возрастным показателем? В чем вообще разница между двумя этими понятиями?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

СОГЛАСНО СЛОВАРЯМ

ЖАРГОН, - [франц. jargon]
Речь какой-л. социальной или профессиональной группы, содержащая большое количество свойственных только этой группе слов и выражений (часто искусственных, тайных или условных); арго. Студенческий, молодёжный ж. Морской ж. Воровской ж.Пользоваться жаргоном. Говорить на жаргоне.

СЛЕНГ,  [англ. slang]
1.Речь социально или профессионально обособленной группы; жаргон.
2.Элементы речи, не совпадающие с нормой литературного языка (обычно экспрессивно окрашенные).

АРГО,  [франц. argot]. Лингв.
Речь какой-л. небольшой социальной замкнутой группы, отличающаяся от общенародного языка лексикой, но не обладающая собственной фонетикой и грамматической системой; жаргон. Воровское а.

КОММЕНТАРИЙ

Три указанных термина имеют как сходство, так и различие. Все они относятся к языку определенных социальных или профессиональных групп, но отличаются по степени замкнутости, по объему использования в речи и по уровню устойчивости и обновляемости.

АРГО -  это язык  замкнутой СОЦИАЛЬНОЙ группы с полной заменой общеупотребительной лексики.

ЖАРГОН охватывает и социальные, и профессиональные группы;  кроме того, он  является менее замкнутым по отношению к этим группам и не полностью изолируется от обычной речи.

СЛЕНГ – это тот же жаргон, но еще более размытый, он может выходить за пределы социальных и профессиональных групп и используется обычными пользователями для обозначения экспрессии речи. Кроме того,  его состав постоянно изменяется и обновляется, что в наибольшей степени свойственно молодежной среде. Соответственно, часто говорится именно о молодежном сленге.

ПРИМЕРЫ

Вы за то, чтобы бабушки/дедушки активно осваивали сленг, дабы суметь понимать своих внуков?  Остановившись в нескольких шагах, они посматривали на Долорес и отпускали шуточки, подвальный смысл которых он тогда еще не улавливал ― возможно, это был какой-то молодежный сленг.  Ох, уж этот новомодный сленг, никак к нему не привыкну, сударь, извините старуху). Этот сленг уже и обывателям знаком, которые внимательно смотрят телевизор.

«Бэпэшка» (от БП ― без породы) ― профессиональный сленг «лошадников». Банковские деньги, извини за сленг, раздрючены. Таков и его последний спектакль ― несмотря на сегодняшний сленг, он пришел в 2002 год из другого времени. За такие песни нас не казнят, но и по радио их не прокрутят, там даже легкий сленг не приветствуется. Этот сленг уже и обывателям знаком, которые внимательно смотрят телевизор.

Раньше жаргон был уделом чётких социальных и профессиональных групп. (Сергей Довлатов). Ну, я тропить-то (идти по следу, охотничий жаргон ― РР) умел. Жаргон компьютерных специалистов ― самый быстрорастущий язык мира.

Answer (score 6):

В происхождении.

"Жаргон" - лет 100-200 назад из французского, а "сленг" - лет 30-50 назад из английского.

...Ох, тут понаписали...
Ладно. Дам развёрнутую версию. Слово "сленг" появилось в нашей стране как жаргонизм, использовавшийся представителями субкультуры хиппи в качестве названия своего жаргона. Т.е. изначально "сленг"="жаргон хиппи".
Сейчас слова "сленг" и "жаргон" полностью взаимозаменяемы (можно встретить версии "профессиональный жаргон", "профессиональный сленг", "молодёжный сленг" и "молодёжный жаргон). Но в научных и "околонаучных" кругах предпочитают слово "жаргон" как "устоявшееся".

Comment: Ох, и понаписали ... Даже словарь указывает, что сленг имеет два значения, и уже поэтому  "сленг" и "жаргон" не являются полностью взаимозаменяемыми. А вся развернутость версии представляет указание на время вхождения слов в язык, при этом не учитывается, что их значение может меняться.

Comment: [В словаре](http://sociolinguistics.academic.ru/634/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B3) я обнаружил **три** значения.. И ни одно из них не выходит за рамки определения [слова "жаргон"](http://popular.academic.ru/1244/%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BD). А умение читать только первый абзац не характерно для исследователя.

Comment: Весьма похвально, что вы обнаружили три значения. При дальнейших исследованиях вы можете также обнаружить несколько словарей с разными толкованиями этого слова. Поэтому могу вам рекомендовать больше общаться с реальными текстами, из которых можно сделать вывод о значении и области употребления слова. Также хотелось бы, чтобы наше общение в большей степени касалось предмета обсуждения, но не переходило на личности. У нас здесь это не принято.

Comment: Полностью согласен с Софией. Ученные еще пришли к единому мнению.

Comment: @София Словарей можно найти сколько угодно. И, надо полагать, при "грамотном" выборе значений можно подобрать для любого слова наиболее удобную трактовку. Именно по этой причине я не люблю пользоваться интернетом в качестве основного источника информации... С другой стороны, "общеупотребительное" значение того или иного термина можно отследить по его использованию. И если Вы укажете ситуацию, в которой термины "сленг" и "жаргон" не эквивалентны - я буду готов прислушаться к Вашей аргументации.

Comment: Ну вот, к примеру, такой текст:  "Студенческий (молодёжный) жаргон составляет в рус­ском языке основу СЛЕНГА — своеобразного жаргонизиро­ванного просторечия молодых поколений, смесь арготиз­мов, жаргонизмов и иноязычных слов:  «прикид» — модная одежда;  «врубиться» — понять, уяснить что-нибудь. Ос­нову молодёжного сленга составляет студенческий жар­гон. Он как бы господствует над младшими жаргонами, например школьными. Темы школьного жаргона разные: «ботаник» — по-старому зубрила; «въезжать» — пони­мать; «фэн» — фанатик; «грины» — обувь;  «гама» — жевательная резинка".

Comment: Всё  равно  это  практически  синонимы.  Здесь  какие-то  попытки  объяснить  разницу  между  этими  словами,  но  всё  очень  субъективно  и  неубедительно.

Comment: Ну да, 150 лет существовало слово "жаргон", вполне справляясь со своими обязанностями, и вдруг решили придумать для него ПОЛНЫЙ синоним. И ЗАЧЕМ? Хорошо бы получить на этот вопрос убедительный и объективный ответ.

Comment: @София. Позволю себе "самоцитирование": __"изначально "сленг"="жаргон хиппи"__ Просто данное социальное явление оказало на российскую, да и мировую культуру весьма сильное влияние. И "сленг" - одно из проявлений этого влияния.

Comment: @София. Ну, и по поводу приведённого Вами текста.. Чем, на Ваш взгляд, __"смесь арготиз­мов, жаргонизмов и иноязычных слов"__ отличается от просто "жаргона"?

Answer (score 4):

Зависит от стиля речи. В разговорной и публицистической - "жаргон" и "сленг" - это как правило одно и тоже, но с разным отношением: "жаргон" имеет негативную окраску, а "сленг" - нейтральную. Слово "сленг" еще может обозначать еще и отдельный жаргонизм.

В научной речи устоявшегося различия между терминами нет. Но так как в терминологии синонимия не приветствуется, то в некоторых работах под "сленгом" подразумевают некий "общий жаргон", что-то среднее между литературным языком и просторечием. Правда особого смысла в таком выделении лично я не вижу. Так как при таком подходе подразумевается, что литературный язык применяется, только в официальной или публичной сферах, а это уже явное упрощение, с целью вместо живого языка в развитии, рассматривать язык-фантом в вакууме. Если слово знают и употребляют все носители, то это уже явно не сленг, не жаргон, а часть литературного языка.